# Has the update process changed in 16.04?

Tags: apt, updates, 16.04

I'm wondering if in 16.04 the update process has changed. Before, it used to look somewhat like this:

[image: apt-get update on a server running Ubuntu 12.04; image courtesy of YouTube user babarehner]

Now, it's like this:

[image: apt-get update on a laptop running Ubuntu 16.04 using the zsh shell; image courtesy of Ask Ubuntu user grooveplex]

Am I missing out on (important) updates or is this normal but new behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> apt has got rather better at producing less junk in its output than it used to, and various server-side changes also mean that it needs to fetch fewer files. [...]

So, yes, this is the new and expected behaviour.

Source:  [This comment](http://web.archive.org/web/20160413053213/https://askubuntu.com/questions/755835/apt-update-in-16-04-is-not-as-long-as-it-used-to-be-in-15-10#comment1128147_755835) by Colin Watson